# What is the precision of number 4.03100?

Tags: conventions, measurements, error-analysis

Trailing 0s occurring after decimal are significant. Like 0.302**000**.
Suppose I got the measurement reading of 4.03100, with clearly 6 significant digits.What's the precision of my measurement? Isn't it 0.00001? Isn't the least count of the instrument the precision of my measurement?

Answer (score 3):

**Accuracy** is a measure of *how close the measured value is to the true value* and is usually expressed in terms of **bias** - we cannot say anything about the accuracy from the number alone. **Precision** is a measure of *how close measured values are to each other* and is usually expressed in terms of **deviation** (spread).

Number in your example $4.03100$ has 6 significant digits, but does not say anything about the precision. Precision is usually indicated in parentheses next to the number. For example, $4.03100(15)$ would mean that some percentage of numbers lie within **confidence interval** $4.03100 \pm 0.00015$. Since the precision is not explicitly stated in your example, you can safely assume that the last digit matters and the confidence interval is $4.03100 \pm 0.00001$.

**Example.** If you measure length with a ruler that has smallest mark of $1 \text{ cm}$, the (theoretical) maximum error of such a measurement would be $\pm 0.01 \text{ m}$: (i) when true value of $11.47999 \text{ m}$ is measured to be $11.47 \text{ m}$ the error is close to $-0.01 \text{ m}$, and (ii) when true value of $11.47001 \text{ m}$ is measured to be $11.48 \text{ m}$ the error is close to $+0.01 \text{ m}$. Hence, we can expect that *majority of measurements* will lie within the $\pm 0.01 \text{ m}$ *error interval*.

The exact percentage of numbers represented by the confidence interval depends on the definition of the number in parenthesis, which is not standardised:

- if the number in parenthesis is **one standard deviation** then 68% of measurements lie within the confidence interval;
- if the number in parenthesis is **two standard deviations** then 95% of measurements lie within the confidence interval etc.

Answer (score 0):

Unless otherwise stated, yes, the precision is the same as if the final $0$ were something different: in other words, all digits are significant. However, in some cases, it's not to the last decimal place, but [that will be indicated with one or more digits in parentheses](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/58667). A source in which such a value appears should make clear with what precision the value is known.

Answer (score 0):

The **Correct_Answer(TM)**   to use  what is called "scientific" or "Engineering" notation.  You must have exactly one digit to the left of the decimal marker.  All digits to the right are significant. There'll be a mantissa ( *10^K) involved.

BTW, this is especially important when reporting large integer values such as "38740000" where the precision is probably 5E4 but it's not guaranteed.

[edit] When taking readings from a machine, you need to understand how the machine creates its digits.  As a simple example, if you measure two quantities with values  5 and 7,  and your formula requires the ratio, $\frac{5}{7}$ , your calculator or MATLAB or whatever will return a stack of digits ( 0.714285714285714) which are clearly in excess of your source data's precision.